# Windows 7 RC1 (x64) and Trend Micro OfficeScan

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, anti-virus

Our IT dept is going to use 7rc1**(7100)** 64 bit.

Unfortunately we are having an issue with OfficeScan.  On install attempt it is saying we need to be member's of Administrators.  I double checked and we are.  Also, UAC is turned off.  We were able to use it under *build 7000* of the BETA but now, nadda.

An there site, [HERE](http://trendmicro.mediaroom.com/index.php?s=43&item=710), it states that they*(will??)* support Windows 7.

Has anyone else experienced this?  Thoughts on a fix?

### EDIT 1

I have gotten past the privledges issue but I am now getting an "incompatible driver" warning.  I triple checked and it is stated that TrendMicro supports 7 and I even found a few (unreachable) references to users who have it running.

Is there anything else I should check?  How do I verify that my components are all up to date?

Ideas?

Comment: Windows 7 has not been released yet, so I doubt OfficeScan will be compatible.  You may have better luck contacting Trend Micro, they may have a beta version you could test with Windows 7 http://esupport.trendmicro.com

Comment: While I agree that Win 7 hasn't been released there are various documents that state OfficeScan 8.0 supports Win 7.  Also, It worked for us in Beta perfectly.

Comment: Even McAfee worked fine in Beta, however the RC contains the complete and finally incompatible program list, and therefore a lot of applications do not work. Trend is on the official Windows 7 Anti VIrus provider page, and it seems like you need the latest beta for official support.

Comment: Please note, last comment made regarding Trend Beta since I didn't see the answer right at the bottom. Please ignore the beta comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to the latest components(*as of 5/13/2009*) from [TrendMicro](http://us.trendmicro.com/us/home/) fixed this issue.

Thanks to all who gave there time.

Answer (score 1):

There's an ACL bug in the 32-bit RC, [this might have something to do with it.](http://blogs.zdnet.com/Bott/?p=1003&tag=nl.e019)

[Hotfix is available through WU.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/970789)

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I forgot to add 64bit as one of my parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the exe under Vista compatibility mode? I've had to use this to install some applications on Win7 rc1.